# Handling empty data from query using listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, sqldatasource

I am currently selecting a value from my first listbox and based on that value it will populate values in my second listbox. However, there are cases when the value from the first listbox may not return anything. I want to know how I would show text on the screen such as "No Data Returned" in the case when the selected value doesn't return anything. Is this possible? I am using sqldatasources for both listboxes.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="SectionItemListBox" DataSourceID="SectionItemSource" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="SectionItem" DataValueField="SectionItemID" AppendDataBoundItems="False" EnableViewState="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SectionItemListBoxSelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:ListBox>


<div style="width:800px; height:auto; overflow:auto">
    <asp:ListBox ID="SectionItemInstructionListBox" DataSourceID="SectionItemInstructionSource" runat="server" DataTextField="Instruction" Visible="True" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with something like...

```
<div style="width:800px; height:auto; overflow:auto">
    <asp:ListBox ID="SectionItemInstructionListBox" DataSourceID="SectionItemInstructionSource" runat="server" DataTextField="Instruction" Visible="True" OnDataBound="SectionItemInstructionListBox_OnDataBound" />

    <asp:Panel ID="NoDataReturnedPanel" Visible="false">
        No Data Returned
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

protected void SectionItemInstructionListBox_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NoDataReturnedPanel.Visible = SectionItemInstructionListBox.Items.Count == 0;
    SectionItemInstructionListBox.Visible = SectionItemInstructionListBox.Items.Count != 0;
}
```